# Issues with MongoDB Connection; python 3.8.7

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am new to coding and am trying to access Mongo DB but keep running into an issue where it ways the module is not found. I know I have installed it, and I have installed the VSCode extension but still have no success.

The MongoDB extension is able to connect to the cluster so I think it is set up correctly.

**It gets stuck on the first line with the error:**

```
Exception has occurred: ModuleNotFoundError

No module named 'pymongo' File "C:\Users\NAME\Documents\Python Scripts\Terminal_Blog\src\app_2.py", line 1, in <module> import pymongo
```

**Code:**

```
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
cluster = "mongodb+srv://REDACTED:REDACTED@cluster0.j4kgr.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
```

**from command prompt:**

```
C:\Users\NAME>pip install pymongo

Requirement already satisfied: pymongo in c:\users\NAME\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages (3.11.2)
```

**Python Version:**

```
C:\Users\NAME>python --version

Python 3.8.7
```

Comment: How are you running your application? Via vscode, or on the same command line where you did your pip install? It's likely VSCode is not using the same python environment.

Comment: its via VS code. how do I ensure they are the same?